# Android:Unable to fetch current location in china using Ti.Geolocation

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

We have developed a global app for both iOS and Android using Appcelerator Titanium. It has few features which mandates using current location to accomplish the task. To do this, we have used Ti.Geolocation to fetch current location.In Android,The app works fine in all parts of the world but not in china.In iOS devices, app works in all parts of the world including china.To further investigate the issue on android, We created a sample app to fetch current location(i.e. latitude and longitude) of the user, using Ti.Geolocation.Android (both Manual Mode and Simple Mode) inline to appcelerator docs. Tested the app in India and USA, it works fine. But , in china it always gives an error "unable to fetch location" or it doesn't work at all.

Kindly, Provide an alternative if somebody has faced similiar issues.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it could depend on accuracy settings which are used for Ti.Geolocation For example I had some problems with geo location on iOS until I set navigation mode: Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Ti.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST_FOR_NAVIGATION; This is available only to iOS but maybe you can experiment with other settings for Android.

Comment: @AndrewTerekhine: Thanks. We tried different modes in android as provided in appcelerator documentation, but didn't succeed.So as a fallback we are now using an api to determine the location, though it is not 100% accurate.